# Extract nearest values from NetCDF file in Python

Tags: python, coordinates, netcdf, spatial-database, xarray

I have a NetCDF database ([link to file](https://mega.nz/file/3GhlmAjD#ABf_DzJFF99nMmpKVoytnom0e7x6hA9nBKGSfmkMDX4)) obtained from [Copernicus Climate Data](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/sis-water-level-change-indicators-cmip6?tab=form) of ~43k unevenly spaced values around the world. Instead of being indexed using (`lat`, `lon`) it uses a sequence of 'stations'. 
My understanding is that `station_x_coordinate` and `station_y_coordinate` are not treated as **dimension coordinates** by xarrays (according to [xarrays docs](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/data-structures.html#coordinates)).

I have a list of my own locations for which I want to get the closest value (i.e., my locations do not necessarily match one of the data points in the NetCDF database).

I would like to use the many selection and interpolation methods of xarray (e.g. `xarray.Dataset.sel` to get values in locations unmatched to data points). But I get errors or problems which are, I guess, related to the fact that I don't have real **dimension coordinates** but variables.

For example, I can use `xarray.Dataset.sel(stations = 11.5, method='nearest')` which will bring the closest value (in this case, station = 12) but this is very unintuitive, as I have no idea how the stations are ordered in the grid. I would rather search using the more sensible indexing (lat, lon) on my target locations. To be clear, I would like to use it like `xarray.Dataset.sel(x = 0, y = 0, method='nearest')` to find the closest value at (`lat` = 0, `lon` = 0) location.

Until now I was able to get all the data points of the NetCDF file into a regular pandas dataframe (columns = ['lat', 'lon', 'value']) and save it as CSV. I can try to make my own function to find the nearest neighbors in 2D space given a target location (it must exist for sure in another library, maybe even numpy or GeoPandas)... but as I said I would like to use the available methods of `xarray` to get values at 'unmatched' locations, interpolate, etc.

What would you do? For example, can I generate a new NetCDF file with a structure that sets `station_x_coordinate` and `station_y_coordinate` of my current NetCDF file as real **dimension coordinates** in the new file? I am no expert in netCDF files, but I assume this way I could use the methods mentioned above. Makes sense?

---

This is the structure of the NetCDF file (output of `xarray.Dataset`):

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                  (stations: 43119)
Coordinates:
  * stations                 (stations) uint16 0 1 2 3 ... 43731 43732 43733
    station_x_coordinate     (stations) float64 ...
    station_y_coordinate     (stations) float64 ...
Data variables:
    return_mean_surge_level  (stations) float64 ...
Attributes: (12/34)
    Conventions:                   CF-1.6
    featureType:                   timeSeries
    id:                            GTSMv3_extreme_value_analysis
    naming_authority:              https://deltares.nl/en
    Metadata_Conventions:          Unidata Dataset Discovery v1.0
    title:                         relative change in return values for surge...
    ...                            ...
    geospatial_vertical_max:       18.564
    geospatial_vertical_units:     m
    geospatial_vertical_positive:  up
    time_coverage_start:           1985
    time_coverage_end:             2050
    experiment:                    highres-future
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like below. First create some test data:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

ds = xr.Dataset({"data": (["stations"], [1.2, 23.7, 77.8])}, coords = {"stations": ("stations", ["la", "lo", "li"]), "lat": ("stations", [45.6, 34.1, 78.2]), "lon": ("stations", [-49.1, 2.1, 179.1])})

lat = 36.3
lon = 3.8
```

Then calculate the distances from your stations to your point of interest and find the station where the distance is smallest:

```
selector = np.sqrt((ds["lat"] - lat)**2 + (ds["lon"] - lon)**2).idxmin()
```

Then use that to filter your dataset:

```
ds.sel(stations = selector)["data"]
```

Very similar, you could also find the index of the station for which the distance is smallest and use that to index your dataset like this:

```
selector = np.sqrt((ds["lat"] - lat)**2 + (ds["lon"] - lon)**2).argmin()
ds.isel(stations = selector)["data"]
```